# k-fold validation package for lmer object in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I need to run 10-fold validation on an lmer object. This model includes fractional polynomial transformations for non-linear growth curves.

I cannot find a k-fold cross validation package that will work on this model! Any ideas?

Comment: @gung yes thats correct, my apologies - I wasnt aware of this etiquette. Migrate away! Thanks

Comment: If anyone ends in this question, this may help: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_of_a_method_for_running_k-fold_cross-validation_on_lmer_objects_from_lme4_package_in_R_studio